# Using Mutex to track another app's lifetime

Tags: c#, c++, mutex

MyApp1 (C#) launches MyApp2 (C#). When MyApp2 is fully up, it executes:

```
new Mutex(true, "MyApp2IsRunning");
```

Meanwhile, MyApp1 has been waiting for this to happen using:

```
Mutex myApp2Mutex = null;
while (myApp2Mutex == null && !timedOut)
{
   try
   {
      myApp2Mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("MyApp2IsRunning");
   }
   catch(WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
}
if (timedout) {return error;}
myApp2Mutex.WaitOne();
```

So if MyApp2 launches within the allotted time, MyApp1 now waits on the MyApp2IsRunning mutex to know when user has exited MyApp2.

I'm rewriting only MyApp1 in C++. What is the equivalent Mutex-related code to detect MyApp2's status? So MyApp1 will still be responsible for launching MyApp2, and I still want it to detect when MyApp2 is up and when the user has exited MyApp2. Same code as above, but in C++.

Comment: Too broad. You probably want to do some Google searching for "mutex IPC" first.

Comment: Use the Windows API mutexes.

Comment: @ChristianHackl What about the post is too broad? I don't think I can be more specific than to provide the exact code I'm trying to port. I'm not a C++ dev so google search results left me wondering about differences between std::mutex and other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pseudocode enables MyApp1 to wait for MyApp2 to launch and then detect when user exits MyApp2:

```
HANDLE hMutex = nullptr;
while (hMutex == nullptr && !timedout)
{
    hMutex = OpenMutex(
        SYNCHRONIZE,
        FALSE,
        "MyApp2IsRunning");
    Sleep(1000);
}
if (timedout){return error;}
DWORD wait_result = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search give you:

HANDLE mutex_you_want = CreateMutex(nullptr, true, "MyApp2IsRunning");

Comment: Having App1 create the mutex does not enable it to detect when App2 is launched and ready.